# How to authenticate with challenge and private keys?

Tags: java, javascript, bitcoinj

I'd like to translate the following `JS` code into `Java` code:

```
var key = new Bitcoin.ECKey(Crypto.util.hexToBytes(SHA256(password)));
var signed_challenge = Crypto.util.bytesToHex(key.sign(Crypto.util.hexToBytes(SHA256(challenge_key))));
```

The `challenge_key` is the desired output and must be send back to the server.

I'm using `bitcoinj` for this. Maybe anyone has already worked with it and can help how the calls in java have to be constructed? I came up with the following, but don't know how to continue:

```
String password; //the private user pw
String challenge; //a string from the server

BigInteger privkey = new BigInteger(Hex.decode(Sha256Hash.create(password.getBytes()).toString()));
ECKey key = new ECKey(privkey);
key.sign(new Sha256Hash(challenge));
```

If what I did is correct: how do I get the challange_key out of the ECkey that I signed?